# Version of Python not showing on cmd

Tags: python, installation, cmd, pip

I have already installed Python in my laptop *(x64)*. I am also trying to install pip (termed as Python Package Index (PyPI)) and it is working when I run the command **pip -V** which displays the version and the location directory of it.
But when I run the command **python --version** , it does not show me the version of it.
[image]
Also when I run the command  it returns this :

> **pip install opencv-python** p' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Do I have to install python again?

Comment: I think you need to add the python environment on your `environment variables` if you're on windows (you are :D)

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: There is no need ever to add the location of the python executable into the content of the `%Path%` environment variable. What you need to learn is how to use full or relative absolute paths and file extensions, e.g. `C:\Python38\python.exe --version`

Answer (score 4):

You need to add python to the windows path like this:

[image]